# R String column matching and adding

Tags: r, string, for-loop, if-statement, google-sheets

I have a dataset called **code_book**, and this dataset has a column named *New Variable*. The content of this column is strings. I want these strings to be the column names of another dataset, which is **data_process**.

But, I just want to pass the string from **code_book** that just begins with the word *Overarching*. There are 9 strings that start with that name.

They should not be added at the same index, but just the next column in **data_process** with NA Value or Zero.

After this, the second task is to add now the strings that start with *Breakfast*, which are 8. These need to be added next to the last column that starts with *Overarching*

I first need to add the first 7, which are *ID, Start, Complete, IPAddress, FirstName, NumID, and Organization.* Then, the ones that start with *Overarching* and then the ones that start with *Breakfast*

I have tried these 2 lines of code, but they are not working.

1.

```
for (x in 1:length(code_book$NewVariable)) {
  if (str_starts(code_book$NewVariable[x], "Overarching")) {
    colnames(data_process)[x] = code_book$NewVariable[x]
  } else if (str_starts(code_book$NewVariable[x], "Breakfast")) {
    colnames(data_process)[x] = code_book$NewVariable[x]
  }
}
```

Also, I tried this, but just for the first word *Overarching*.

```
ifelse(grepl("Overarching", code_book$NewVariable),
       colnames(data_process)[x] <- code_book$NewVariable[x],
       code_book)
```

Any ideas of how can I accomplish this?

Here are the 2 datasets.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1xpbR1GaOSi8qSOFS7rhfZKuI-jdYuSsq?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

```
others <- c("ID", "Start", "Complete", "IPAddress", "FirstName", "NumID", "Organization")

# add the first seven
colnames(data_process)[1:7] <- others

overarching <- grepl("Overarching", code_book$NewVariable)

# add overarching
colnames(data_process)[overarching] <- code_book$NewVariable[overarching]

breakfast <- grepl("Breakfast", code_book$NewVariable)

# add breakfast
colnames(data_process)[breakfast] <- code_book$NewVariable[breakfast]
```

Output:

```
> colnames(data_process)
  [1] "ID"                              "Start"                          
  [3] "Complete"                        "IPAddress"                      
  [5] "FirstName"                       "NumID"                          
  [7] "Organization"                    "X8"                             
  [9] "X9"                              "X10"                            
 [11] "OverarchingImproveRelationships" "OverarchingNewRelationships"    
 [13] "OverarchingTrust"                "OverarchingKnowledge"           
 [15] "OverarchingReferral"             "OverarchingConnections"         
 [17] "OverarchingSupport"              "OverarchingBest"                
 [19] "OverarchingChanges"              "X20"                            
 [21] "X21"                             "X22"                            
 [23] "X23"                             "X24"                            
 [25] "X25"                             "X26"                            
 [27] "X27"                             "X28"                            
 [29] "X29"                             "X30"                            
 [31] "X31"                             "X32"                            
 [33] "X33"                             "X34"                            
 [35] "X35"                             "X36"                            
 [37] "X37"                             "X38"                            
 [39] "X39"                             "X40"                            
 [41] "X41"                             "X42"                            
 [43] "X43"                             "X44"                            
 [45] "X45"                             "X46"                            
 [47] "X47"                             "X48"                            
 [49] "X49"                             "X50"                            
 [51] "X51"                             "X52"                            
 [53] "X53"                             "X54"                            
 [55] "X55"                             "X56"                            
 [57] "X57"                             "X58"                            
 [59] "X59"                             "X60"                            
 [61] "X61"                             "X62"                            
 [63] "X63"                             "X64"                            
 [65] "X65"                             "X66"                            
 [67] "X67"                             "X68"                            
 [69] "BreakfastAttend"                 "BreakfastMeet"                  
 [71] "BreakfastDiscuss"                "BreakfastLearn"                 
 [73] "BreakfastShare"                  "BreakfastNew"                   
 [75] "BreakfastBest"                   "BreakfastChange"                
 [77] "BreakfastUnable"                 "BreakfastUnable1"               
 [79] "BreakfastUnable2"                "BreakfastUnable3"               
 [81] "BreakfastUnable4"                "BreakfastUnable5"               
 [83] "BreakfastUnableOther"            "X84"                            
 [85] "X85"                             "X86"                            
 [87] "X87"                             "X88"                            
 [89] "X89"                             "X90"                            
 [91] "X91"                             "X92"                            
 [93] "X93"                             "X94"                            
 [95] "X95"                             "X96"                            
 [97] "X97"                             "X98"                            
 [99] "X99"                             "X100"                           
[101] "X101"                            "X102"                           
[103] "X103"                            "X104"                           
[105] "X105"                            "X106"                           
[107] "X107"                            "X108"                           
[109] "X109"                            "X110"                           
[111] "X111"                            "X112"                           
[113] "X113"                            "X114"                           
[115] "X115"                            "X116"                           
[117] "X117"                            "X118"                           
[119] "X119"                            "X120"                           
[121] "X121"                            "X122"                           
[123] "X123"                            "X124"                           
[125] "X125"                            "X126"                           
[127] "X127"                            "X128"                           
[129] "X129"                            "X130"                           
[131] "X131"                            "X132"                           
[133] "X133"                            "X134"                           
[135] "X135"                            "X136"                           
[137] "X137"                            "X138"                           
[139] "X139"                            "X140"                           
[141] "X141"                            "X142"                           
[143] "CardEmail"
```

Comment: Thank you very much [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4145280/mark) How to do so with no spaces between columns? First Overarching should be at X8 and the first breakfast column should be just next to the last Overarching. @Mark

Comment: are you wanting to drop the other columns? Or are you wanting to name the first n columns, where n is length(others) + number of Overarching columns + number of Breakfast columns

Comment: Correct [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4145280/mark), the second option. First the N columns, then the Overarching columns, and then the Breakfast column. Surely I would be adding more that start with another word, and so on.